Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'. but I don't know why? prebuild is good. but production build is not
I'm tried my react-native application build with expo-cli, but build failed with this error:

Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'

because I input local video file. It does not find my video file.
When I build with development build, it works expo go application
but production build is not.

Error: Unable to resolve module ..\assets\avatar.mp4 from /home/expo/workingdir/build/app/talk.js: ..\assets\avatar.mp4 could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules
314 |
315 |       <Video
316 |         source={require('..\assets\avatar.mp4')}
|                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
317 |         style={styles.video}
318 |         resizeMode="cover"
319 |         controls={false}

When I delete this code, build is successful.
But I need this! How to fix it?

Does it work when you provide the URL of any random video ?

Yes random URL video is work and very successful build. just local file did

I have fix it. It's just need expo-asset

Great work ....
